# Not able to debug/trace a large Win64 application

Tags: debugging, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe6, win64

I have a large application of around 1 million lines of code, with 500 .dfm and .pas files spread out into many folders.

Not many user components are used, only a few. No external packages are used/embedded.

When I try to trace it or breakpoint as Win64-bit exe target, it does not stop, the breakpoint line stays green.

As a 32-bit target exe, no problem at all.

This is run on a x64 OS.

If I try with a small basic test application (around 1000 lines) I can trace it as a Win64 target.

Same behavior with XE3, XE6 and XE7.

I discarded all config files from my project and only used the DPR file to load, so that the config is reset from scratch.

I can compile, no problem, but the same issue there, no way to trace it. Breakpoints stay green.

This is really annoying because I have no means to debug / trace my application.

Any workaround would be highly appreciated.

I have no clue where it comes from.

Comment: It's the Build configuration set to Debug mode in your x64 App?

Comment: What about a brand new vanilla project?

Comment: yes this is set to DEBUG mode

Comment: Brand new vanilla: I have tried by just keeping the DPR file and deleted all the others dproj and other stuff : same thing

Comment: I can trace into as assembler CPU view, but not very usefull to me...

Comment: What about a brand new vanilla project?

Comment: new vanilla project : what do you mean ?

Comment: Brand new project. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_vanilla

Comment: I did that ; and this is the same behavior, just keeping the good all DPR file and deleting the other files.

Comment: I don't know why you need to keep files, and delete others. Never mind.

Comment: Maybe there's an error in your code preventing it from reaching the particular line you're trying to debug? Try placing your breakpoint earlier.